# How can I show a mouse hover info box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mouseover

I have a php website where I use mysql as database. I want a feature like https://www.instantssl.com their bottom right corner seal.

Its showing specific info when anyone hover the mouse or click it.

I want the same feature. how can I do it?

Comment: With [`jQuery.mouseover()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `<div>` element within your page that holds the content you want displayed on mouse over. Once the mouse over event is trigger, you could then hide/show it. Things you should research:

1. `onmouseover` event
2. `.show()` jquery
3. `.hide()` jquery

These are the three basic events that you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Buy I want to show specific mysql data. How can I do that?